# TypeError: combine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source2'

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python now, I'm trying to finish the assignment about the Queue. This is the question and my code; I'm trying to test my code but it outputs an error.

```
def combine(self, source1, source2):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Combines two source queues into the current target queue.
    When finished, the contents of source1 and source2 are interlaced
    into target and source1 and source2 are empty.
    Order of source values is preserved.
    (iterative algorithm)
    Use: target.combine(source1, source2)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        source1 - an array-based queue (Queue)
        source2 - an array-based queue (Queue)
    Returns:
        None
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    while len(source1._values) > 0 and len(source2._values) > 0:
        self._values.append(source1._values.pop())
        self._values.append(source2._values.pop())
    while len(source1._values) > 0:
        self._values.append(source1._values.pop())
    while len(source2._values) > 0:
        self._values.append(source2._values.pop())
    return None
```

and the is the test program

```
from functions import combine
from Queue_array import Queue

data1 = [1, 2, 3]
data2 = [4, 5, 6]

s1 = Queue()
s2 = Queue()
target = Queue()
for v in data1:
    s1._values.append(v)

for w in data2:
    s2._values.append(w)

target = combine(s1, s2)
for i in target:
    print(i)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CP164-2\maxx7140_a04\src\t03.py", line 26, in <module>
    target = combine(s1, s2)
TypeError: combine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source2'
```

I'm not sure what to do to correct my test program.

this is the Queue program

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Initializes an empty queue. Data is stored in a Python list.
        Use: queue = Queue()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns:
            a new Queue object (Queue)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._values = []
    
    def insert(self, value):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Adds a copy of value to the rear of the queue.
        Use: queue.insert(value)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Parameters:
            value - a data element (?)
        Returns:
            None
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """

        self._values.append(deepcopy(value))

        return
```

I'm not sure which part goes wrong, I am not particularly skilled in the use of Class and Queue.

Comment: `combine` accepts three arguments: `self`, `source1` and `source2`. But you're only passing two. What is `self` supposed to be?

Comment: `combine` is intended to be a method of a `Queue` object, not a free function. Look at how it's called in the doc string, after `Use: `.

Comment: @CrazyChucky From how it's imported (`from functions import combine`) seems like it's a free function. I assume it was copied by st XA from elsewhere (e.g. I found it [here](https://www.coursehero.com/file/49812693/functionspy/))?

Comment: @decorator-factory Well, the version you've linked clearly is written as a standalone function. But the questioner's version has been modified to accept `self` rather than instantiating a new `Queue` on its own. If it's *not* meant to be used as a method on a `Queue` object, I'm really confused about what their teacher is doing, and why. After all, the usage specified in the doc string explicitly portrays it called as a method.

Comment: They may have created an independent wrapper function `combine(target, source1, source2)` that simply does `target.combine(source1, source2)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code. Here, we don't have the code for `functions` or `Queue_array`, so we can only guess at the solution. Specifically, it's not clear why `functions.combine()` exists, whether it's the same `combine` as in the first snippet, or whether `Queue_array.Queue` has its own `combine` method. It'd also help to provide the expected output for completeness. For more tips, see [ask] and [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

The `combine()` function appears to have been extracted from the class and turned into a top-level function. It requires the `target` to be its first argument (called `self` in the function definition), and modifies it in place.

So change:

```
target = combine(s1, s2)
```

to:

```
combine(target, s1, s2)
```

You probably shouldn't be writing things like

```
s1._values.append(v)
```

By convention, attribute names that begin with `_` are intended to be internal, not directly accessed from outside the class. You should use the `Queue.insert()` method:

```
s1.insert(v)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add Queue to the question, I've updated my question.

Comment: I updated the last part of the answer to show what method to use to add to the queue.

Comment: thank you, I tried to change append to insert in the above test program, but it still shows "TypeError: combine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source2' ", Do I need to make any changes to "target = combine(s1, s2) for i in target: print(i)"? Or maybe somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. That's in the first part of my answer. You have to change that to `target.combine(s1, s2)` or `combine(target, s1, s2)`

Comment: When I try the "target.combine(s1, s2)" , it output "AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'combine'", and when I try "combine(target, s1, s2)", it just output a None

Comment: Of course it outputs `None` -- the last line of the function is `return None`. It modifies the target in place, it doesn't return it.

Comment: sorry i missed that, thank you for your help